# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'option_chain'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, yfinance

I am attempting to download stock option data via the library yfinance for a list of stock tickers represented by the variable: "tickers" for options with an expiration date represented by: "exp_date".

Frankly, I don't even know if my loop/append is correct as I am new to coding, but I am getting the error message:

> "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'option_chain'".

I only get the error message if I try to do this loop for all stock tickers. If I manually input a single ticker and manually input the expiration date instead of using the "exp_date" variable, it works perfectly.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Get Friday of current week for expiration date
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
exp_date = (current_time.date() - datetime.timedelta(days=current_time.weekday()) + datetime.timedelta(days=4))

# Get options data and put in dataframe
opt_df = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in tickers:
    opt = ticker.option_chain(exp_date)
    opt_df.pd.Dataframe.append(opt)
```

Comment: I don't see the definition of `tickers` could you add it ? Also try to debug by yourself with like `print(type(ticker), ticker)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ticker` is the ticker symbol, not the ticker information returned by yfinance.

```
for symbol in tickers:
    ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    opt = ticker.option_chain(exp_date)
    opt_df.pd.Dataframe.append(opt)
```